# Go type definition and initialize a pointer

Tags: go, pointers, type-definition

I'm new to Go. I'm trying to use type definition to customize a stack.

```
type Stack []int

func main() {
    slice := make([]int, 0)
    var stack Stack = make([]int, 0)
    fmt.Println(slice, stack)
    // var pstack *Stack = &slice
```

Type Stack is an `[]int`.

I found it possible to assign the result of `make([]int, 0)` to the variable `stack` of type `Stack`. However, when I try to initialize a pointer of stack using `&` in front of the variable `slice`, just like the commented line in the code, it raises compile error that states:

> cannot use &slice (value of type *[]int) as *Stack value in variable
> declaration, compiler(IncompatibleAssign)

I would like to know if there is a simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability. `var stack Stack = make([]int, 0)` works because `Stack` and `[]int` have the same _underlying type_ and the latter is not a named type. `var pstack *Stack = &slice` doesn't work because none of the conditions for assignability are fulfilled; in particular, `*Stack` and `*[]int` do _not_ have the same underlying type.

Comment: `var pstack *Stack = &stack` works. Also `var pstack *Stack = new(Stack)`. Also `var pstack *Stack = &Stack{}`.